# MySQL spatial geom query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, postgis

Hi I'm very new regarding PostGIS so forgive me if this is a dumb question.
I'm trying to make this query run fast

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3..,
b.col1,  b.col2, b.col3.....

FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b 
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(b.Shape, a.Point)
```

index:
`Spatial Shape_Idx ON table2 (Shape)`
`ID_Idx on table2(ID)`

Explain shows

```
select type: Simple
table:b 
type:ALL 
possible Keys: Shape
rows: 40k+

table:a
type:ALL
rows: 7m+
Extra: Using where, Using join buffer
```

table2 has a unique id for each geom shape and spatial index doesn't seem to work?
What should be my approach to solve this problem? Any tips is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In postgis you use `st_dwithin` in the where clause ;)

Comment: Get the "Optimizer Trace" output.  Even if it is well optimized, it must do 7M+ Spatial lookups.  This can't be fast.